# css for chat room speech bubble position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I am trying to design a chat room and am stuck on the css of speech bubbles.

**What I want**
Blue speech bubbles on the right and grey ones on the left.
[image]

**At the moment**
I tried several answers I found on SO like position relative/absolute. But none of the answers worked for me. If someone can help me here itd be great.
[image]

**Html**

```
<div class="card-body p-3 pt-0">
    <div class="my-1 rounded-lg ">
        <div class="position-relative w-100">

            @foreach ($chats as $chat)
            <p class="text-xs">
                {{$chat->created_at}} @ {{$chat->name}}
            </p>
            <div class="border-0 {{ $chat->user_identifier == 'SELF' ? 'chat-bubble-send' : 'chat-bubble-receive' }}">
                <p class="text-sm ">
                    {{ $chat->message }}
                </p> 
            </div>
            @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.chat-bubble-receive p {
    background: #42a5f5;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 3px 20px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 75%;
    padding: 7px 13px 7px 13px;
}

.chat-bubble-send p {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #000 !important;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 3px;
    display: block;
    max-width: 75%;
    padding: 7px 13px 7px 13px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
}
```

**When the message is short**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have invalid HTML, since `<li>` should be accompanied by a `<ul>`

Comment: You are using a lot of CSS classes which your code shown here doesn't have. It's unclear how these affect your problem.

Comment: @Roy youre right. Forgot to change that. The <div> was a <ul> before. Fixed it now..

Comment: Don't heavily style the `p` element, use the DIV instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Chat messages using CSS Flex

[image]

- Inside a flex parent, to determine the left/right *position* of the message elements — use `margin-(left/right)` set to `auto`
- [When using `position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) make sure to use `position:relative;` (or any other position other than `static`) on a parent element.
- Use `bottom: 100%` to position the absolute time details on top of the first message.
- "Hide" `display:none;` by default the "name+datetime" pseudo element, but show it `display:block;` only for the first message in group by using `:first-child` and the `+` *next sibling combinator* selector
- You could use the [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the extra details (time etc) and use a [pseudo element like `::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to than populate it with that value using `content: attr(data-time)`

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.chat {
  --rad: 20px;
  --rad-sm: 3px;
  font: 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 75%;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.msg.sent {
  border-radius: var(--rad) var(--rad-sm) var(--rad-sm) var(--rad);
  background: #42a5f5;
  color: #fff;
  /* moves it to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
}

.msg.rcvd {
  border-radius: var(--rad-sm) var(--rad) var(--rad) var(--rad-sm);
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #555;
  /* moves it to the left */
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Improve radius for messages group */

.msg.sent:first-child,
.msg.rcvd+.msg.sent {
  border-top-right-radius: var(--rad);
}

.msg.rcvd:first-child,
.msg.sent+.msg.rcvd {
  border-top-left-radius: var(--rad);
}


/* time */

.msg::before {
  content: attr(data-time);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #888;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Hidden by default */
  display: none;
}

.msg.sent::before {
  right: 15px;
}

.msg.rcvd::before {
  left: 15px;
}


/* Show time only for first message in group */

.msg:first-child::before,
.msg.sent+.msg.rcvd::before,
.msg.rcvd+.msg.sent::before {
  /* Show only for first message in group */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div data-time="16:35" class="msg sent">Hi!<br>What's up?</div>
  <div data-time="Anna 16:36" class="msg rcvd">Hi dear! <br>Doing some CSS research, you?</div>
  <div data-time="16:38" class="msg sent">Also learning some cool CSS stuff </div>
  <div data-time="16:38" class="msg sent">!!</div>
  <div data-time="16:38" class="msg sent">Up for a coffee today? ☕</div>
  <div data-time="Anna 16:40" class="msg rcvd">It would be a pleasure!</div>
  <div data-time="Anna 16:40" class="msg rcvd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice use of the `content: attr(data-)` -- You may want to explain that a bit.

Comment: @Roko hey thanks for this. Its very clean. Just one problem I encountered, when the message is short the "Ann 16:36" part hides behind the speech bubble. Can you tell me how that could be solved? Ive attached an image in the question.

Comment: @haashe PS the above times are handled by CSS-only in this demo, but it would be best to handle that using JS using some logic like: *show name+time if: 1. is first message in group, 2. time between last message is >10min*. The second case is if one person sent several messages in a row, you would want to notify that some group of messages was posted recently.

Comment: @Roko thanks for the additional info about times in JS. It cleared some questions I had. About the times in css, at the moment when the message is short, the times is no longer hidden behind the bubble but is shown in 2 lines, is it possible to make it show in one line no matter the size of bubble?

Comment: Nice found! @haashe simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to the ::before pseudo. Edited my answer.

Comment: Motivation for Today and forever for me in coding @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @ash thank you very much ;) yes, it's nice to be a developer today with modern browsers following standards.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using **flex** magic with a new row-div wrapping every bubble.

```css
.row:nth-of-type(2n) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bubble { 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bubble">
        <p>First bubble</p>
        <small>Details</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bubble">
        <p>Second bubble</p>
        <small>Details</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bubble">
        <p>Third bubble</p>
        <small>Details</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bubble">
        <p>Fourth bubble</p>
        <small>Details</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And of course `text-align: right` for the bubbles on the right. Let me know if that works for you and if so, then mark my answer as useful :)

Comment: `.row:nth-of-type(2n)` is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Can you explain it's not a right approach @RokoC.Buljan?

Comment: I mean, it's OK for this specific demo purpose, but in a chat, a user can send multiple messages in a row.

Comment: Right. I haven't thought about that option. In my case it'd be recommended to create a row and then add bubbles in the specific row so it stayed in the div.

Comment: A grouping row would be nice, but such would complicate unnecessarily the backend code (for the first messages render), and even the JavaScript code (for the dynamic view update). See my answer for a possible solution - using CSS alone.